Make mypy to understand, that the attribute is not None
quick description of my environment:
- django                      4.2.11
- mypy                        1.9.0
- django-stubs                4.2.5

Here is a synthetic example I made bellow, just for that post, please don't judge me for the meaning of names, etc. The point is how to handle the mypy error...
I have two models, one refers to another via ForeignKey:
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, blank=False, null=True, ...)

then I have a set of similar functions, for each of them there is a rule: we check, that author is not None, if it is - then raise an error: ImproperlyConfigured:
def _check_configuration(book: Book) -> None:
    if not book.author:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured()

def func1(book: Book) -> int:
    _check_configuration(book)
    ....
    author_name = book.author.name  # here it comes...

def func2(book: Book) -> str:
    _check_configuration(book)
    ....

For DRY purpose, I use validation function. If I put if book.author is None... right into the func1 - then the error disappears.
Here is the error:
error: ... "Author | None" has no attribute "name" [union-attr]

How to explain to mypy that the author is not None for sure?
Thanks!
ChatGPT and Googling. ChatGPT returns stupid advices about that problem and for Google, I even can't formulate the request, everything i've tried - guides me to another problems...

What if you use a decorator instead?

Could you elaborate, how would that help?

make _check_configuration return the author?

Any of TypeIs / TypeGuard / passing the already checked author to func1 and func2 instead / anthony's comment above should work while following DRY.

@anthonysottile, thank you for the comment, i have missed that. Unfortunately, that graceful solution also doesn't solve the issue. In NDA purposes, I made a very basic example, the real validation function is much more complicated. And a return of a tuple of something - also may harm the real use case. But I will use that advice in another cases, as long as the advices about decorator and assertion.

in that case I'll VTC as not-reproducible -- can't help you with a problem we can't see

For a check as simple as this, I would use an assertion - you can use the custom error, the type checker can infer the typing information, and the repeated line is barely any longer (I've used dataclasses below to present the example, but it would work with anything):
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Author:
    name: str

@dataclass
class Book:
    author: Author | None

class ImproperlyConfigured(ValueError):
    pass

def func1(book: Book) -> str:
    assert book.author, ImproperlyConfigured
    author_name = book.author.name
    return author_name

func1(Book(None))


Thank you for your elegant solution, that looks way more better, but unfortunately doesn't solve my issue: _check_configuration is way more complected in real code, than here. I didn't share the real code in NDA purposes.
